# Is there any foreign players represented Ireland in county series

Tags: cricket

Has any overseas player played for Ireland in matches against English County Sides prior to their admission as a full member of ICC.

Comment: Hi Madhawavish could you confirm do you mean did Ireland have an overseas player when they played Counties in England or something else ?

Comment: @ Ben Whyall yes it's

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [this article suggests](https://www.rte.ie/sport/cricket/2007/0509/217596-cricket/), a number have done it in the past when Ireland were not at the level they now play at.

Comment: Once the vague statement is accounted for, this is a link-only answer. Please include your own description of the players you claim to match the condition in the question.